# Javascript on button click add value to text box

Tags: javascript, calculator

Just a super simple javascript question, but i cannot find out how it works

Need to get script output to the input.

original script on http://jsfiddle.net/mYuRK/

Thanks!

```js
var theTotal = 0;
$('button').click(function(){
   theTotal = Number(theTotal) + Number($(this).val());
    $('.tussenstand').text("Total: "+theTotal);        
});

$('.tussenstand').text("Total: "+theTotal);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="tussenstand">

<button value="1">1</button>
<button value="2">2</button>
<button value="4">4</button>
<button value="6">6</button>
```

Comment: Use `#tussenstand` instead of `.tussenstand` as selector.

Comment: @Guffa , the text should be replaced with the val , as well

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you're using an id for the input you need to use `#` instead of `.` for the selector. And for `input` you have to assign the value.

So instead of `$('.tussenstand').text(` use `$('#tussenstand').val(`.

```js
var theTotal = 0;
$('button').click(function(){
   theTotal = Number(theTotal) + Number($(this).val());
    $('#tussenstand').val("Total: "+theTotal);        
});

$('#tussenstand').val("Total: "+theTotal);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="tussenstand">

<button value="1">1</button>
<button value="2">2</button>
<button value="4">4</button>
<button value="6">6</button>
```

Answer (score 4):

Change the class selector to an id selector in your JS, and use `val()` instead of `text()`.

```
var theTotal = 0;
$('button').click(function(){
   theTotal = Number(theTotal) + Number($(this).val());
    $('#tussenstand').val("Total: "+theTotal);        
});

$('#tussenstand').val("Total: "+theTotal);
```

`val()` is what jQuery uses to edit/retrieve the value of a textbox.

Answer (score 0):

Use this SCRIPT:

```
<script>
        function insertTextInInputValue(buttonValueIs){
            var inputElementIs = document.getElementById("tussenstand");
            inputElementIs.value = inputElementIs.value + buttonValueIs;
        }
    </script>
```

with the HTML:

```
<input id="tussenstand">
<button onclick="insertTextInInputValue(1);">1</button>
<button onclick="insertTextInInputValue(2);">2</button>
<button onclick="insertTextInInputValue(3);">3</button>
<button onclick="insertTextInInputValue(4);">4</button>
<button onclick="insertTextInInputValue(5);">5</button>
<button onclick="insertTextInInputValue(6);">6</button>
```